# Bash Script To Remove Users From Wordlist

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7, userdel

I wrote the following script to remove users from a wordlist. The wordlist has 3 or 4 fields which are First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, and User ID. I am using awk to create a username that comprises of the user's firstname initial, lastname and last two digits of their ID. Then using the command userdel with flag r to remove users with their home directories as well.

However when I run the script it gives me an error saying the following:

```
Usage: userdel [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -f, --force                   force some actions that would fail otherwise
                                e.g. removal of user still logged in
                                or files, even if not owned by the user
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -r, --remove                  remove home directory and mail spool
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -Z, --selinux-user            remove any SELinux user mapping for the user
```

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Removing users using positional parameters

getusername(){
    line=${1}
    len=`echo ${line}|awk '{ FS = " " } ; { print NF}'`
    if [[ ${len} -eq 3 ]]
    then
        initial=`echo ${line}| awk {'print $1'} |cut -c1`
        lastname=`echo ${line} | awk {'print $2'}`
        id=`echo ${line}| awk {'print $3'}|grep -o '..$'`
        username=`echo ${initial}${lastname}${id} |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
    elif [[ ${len} -eq 4 ]]
    then
        initial=`echo ${line} | awk {'print $1'} |cut -c1`
        lastname=`echo ${line} | awk {'print $3'}`
        id=`echo ${line}| awk {'print $4'}|grep -o '..$'`
        username=`echo ${initial}${lastname}${id} |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
    else
        echo "Line ${line} is not expected as it should be considered for creating Username and Password"
    fi    
}

sudo userdel -r  $getusername
```

Comment: There is no such variable as `getusername` so `$getusername` expands to nothing.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: you can reduce the number of processes your `getusername` function launches by relying on `awk` to do anything that `cut` or `grep -o` can do. i.e. `initial=\`echo ${line}| awk '{print substr($1,1,1)'}\`` and `d=\`echo ${line}| awk '{print substr($4, length($4)-1)}'\`` . AND you can get `len` much easier with `line="${1}";len="$(#line}"`, which of course is redundant, because you can test `if [ "${#1}" -eq 3 ] ; ....` and it still pretty self-documenting. The less code, the fewer places for it to break ;-) !  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How to invoke `userdel`?

`userdel -r username`

This deletes the account of user **username**, and removes that user's home directory and associated mail files.

For that, you need to use a variable instead of to invoke a function.

Otherwise `userdel` will complain, like it is already doing or like just typing `userdel`.